# Behavior of Win32 named pipe in duplex mode

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Trying to read and write through a named pipe between a single server and single client without overlapped mode.
Two threads are being run for read and write separately. My understanding as per the documentation is, a single connection will have both in and out buffer. So I should be able to read and write parallely with a single instance of pipe.
Have written a simple test code to write from server to client in a loop. The moment the read thread on server calls ReadFile, the write thread gets stuck at WriteFile. Could someone explain what is the behavior in this case?

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) says "**The pipe server should not perform a blocking read operation until the pipe client has started**". But the blocking ReadFile is being done after the client starts receiving data from the write thread.

Update 1: I understand that the ReadFile is blocking the WriteFile here. But I am looking for Microsoft's documentation which has the explanation for this behavior. Any links to that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069172/duplex-named-pipe-hangs-on-a-certain-write may be relevant.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for that. Actually I have read that before posting this. But it's no where documented in msdn that simultaneous read and write is not allowed in blocking mode. As long as there are two different buffers for read and write, technically it shouldn't be a problem. But I am seeking for more information on this.

Comment: *The moment the read thread on server calls ReadFile, the write thread gets stuck at WriteFile.* - this and must be. if file open in synchronous mode - all io operation is sequential. new io operation not begin, until old not finished. so if now read io active - you can not not only write. even if you say query file name - this query will block, until read not finished. so have different treads for read and write not help here at all. you need use asynchronous io

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I understood the behaviour. But where is it documented?

Comment: yes, documented. [*All I/O on such a file is serialized across all threads using the returned handle.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile)

Comment: also here [*If this flag is not specified, then I/O operations are serialized*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) (about `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`)

Comment: @RbMm Thats one good way of looking at this issue. CreateFile is not being called from server directly. The call with which the handle is obtained is CreateNamedPipe. Since both read and write buffers are obtained, I was thinking that the windows would have implemented some sort of asynchronous mechanism when PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX is given. Need to debug the assembly itself to understand more. Anyway thanks

Comment: @SolidMercury - the `CreateNamedPipe` internally call `ZwCreateNamedPipeFile` and this call internal call [`IoCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatefile) with `CreateFileTypeNamedPipe`. and *All operations on the file are performed synchronously* - all this related to `FILE_OBJECT` no matter, which api you call for create it

Comment: *Since both read and write buffers are obtained, I was thinking that the windows would have implemented some sort of asynchronous mechanism when PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX is given* - you mistake. you have [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) with `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` flag. for such object *All I/O on such a file is serialized across all threads using the returned handle.*

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for the explanation. I understood after the NtCreateFile link you shared. But what I was telling is CreateNamedPipe would have called NtCreateFile in async mode. I will take a look at assembly to see if FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO is indeed set or not. Once I confirm, I would post a comment and you can put your comments as answer. I will happily accept that as an answer post confirming.:-)

Comment: the `CreateNamedPipe` not call `NtCreateFile` it call another, undocumented api - [`NtCreateNamedPipeFile`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntioapi.h#L1115) - (look here for *CreateOptions* parameter - same as in `NtCreateFile`) however all this calls intersect in `IoCreateFile` (already documented api. documentation not perfect but as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The moment the read thread on server calls ReadFile, the write thread
>   gets stuck at WriteFile.

A pipe is referenced by two kernel file objects (see [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object)), one at each end of the pipe. On the server side, [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) internally calls the native system function [`NtCreateNamedPipeFile`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntioapi.h#L1115), which in the kernel calls [`IoCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatefile) with `CreateFileType` passed as `CreateFileTypeNamedPipe`.

Each file object may be opened for either [synchronous or asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o). (Asynchronous I/O is also referred to as overlapped I/O.) The I/O mode is determined by the presence of the `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` flag in the file object. If the flag is set, the I/O mode is synchronous. Otherwise the I/O mode is asynchronous.

For synchronous mode, the I/O manager serializes all I/O operations on the file object. Concurrent I/O operations on the file in other threads will block (i.e. wait to begin) until the current operation has completed. Even querying the file name (also an I/O operation) will block. (This is a known problem for system-level tools such as Sysinternals handle.exe. This can block if we try to query the pipe name while the system is waiting for a synchronous read to complete.)

Using several threads (e.g. read in one thread, write in another) does not help here at all. Asynchronous I/O is ideal here. It's more efficient (fewer threads) and never deadlocks.

---

The native NT API and Windows API use different options to specify the I/O mode.

The NT API (e.g. `NtCreateFile`, `NtCreateNamedPipeFile`) by default assumes asynchronous mode. Using synchronous mode requires a particular create option, as discussed in the documentation:

> The `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` and `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`
>   *CreateOptions* flags, which are mutually exclusive as their names suggest, specify that all I/O operations on the file will be
>   synchronous—as long as they occur through the file object referred to
>   by the returned FileHandle. **All I/O on such a file is serialized
>   across all threads using the returned handle.**

With either create option, the `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` flag is set in the file object. `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` additionally sets the `FO_ALERTABLE_IO` flag.

The Windows API (e.g. `CreateFileW`, `CreateNamedPipeW`, `CreatePipe`) by default assumes synchronous I/O mode. For this it passes the  NT create option `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` when calling underlying NT API functions. The Windows API flag `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` overrides the default to request asynchronous I/O mode.